# Jetpack compose gradient image on top of image

Tags: gradient, android-jetpack-compose

I have the below code in xml layout, which I would like to move to compose and havong a hard time to get it right

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/image"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="375:258"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_gradient"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/gradient"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/image1" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I tried in Compose using a Box that didn't work

```
 Box {
            Image(painter = painterResource(
                id = R.drawable.image1),
                contentDescription = null,
            )

            Image(painter = painterResource(
                id = R.drawable.gradient),
                contentDescription = null,
                contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
            )
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably your gradient image has zero size.

You can use [`Modifier.matchParentSize`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/BoxScope#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).matchParentSize()): it is available in `BoxScope`. Apply it to the gradient image to make its size equal to the size of the main image.

```
Box {
    Image(painter = painterResource(
        id = R.drawable.image1),
        contentDescription = null,
    )

    Image(painter = painterResource(
        id = R.drawable.gradient),
        contentDescription = null,
        contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds,
        modifier = Modifier.matchParentSize()
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create the gradient in a composy way

```
Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        .background(Color.White)) {

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(color = Color.White)
                .height(200.dp)
        ) {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(
                    id = R.drawable.ty
                ),
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
            )
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(
                        brush = Brush.verticalGradient(
                            colors = listOf(
                                MaterialTheme.colors.primary.copy(alpha = 0.5f),
                                MaterialTheme.colors.primaryVariant.copy(alpha = 0.5f)
                            )
                        )
                    )
                    .fillMaxSize()
            )
        }
    }
}
```